# Как прибиндить IsSelected у TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть TabControl у которого ItemsSource прибинден к коллекции во ViewModel-и. Коллекция тоже состоит из других ViewModel-ей у которых в частности есть свойство IsSelected. Надо прибиндить IsSelected у TabItem-ов  к этому свойству. Только я не знаю как... Я задаю контент TabItem-ов с помощью ContentTemplate. А шаблон просто в ресурсах определен как DataTemplate. Т.е. у него нет свойства IsSelected, он вообще никак не относится к TabItem, это просто шаблон. Как сделать?

Comment: У самого TabControl смотрите SelecteItem={Binding

Comment: @vitidev Так это ведь совсем другое. Мне надо чтобы биндинг был к каждому итему потому что это как бы внутренняя ViewModel каждого элемента, а так как вы предлагаете биндинг будет к ViewModel-и содержащей коллекцию.

Comment: есть 2 пути: 
1)простой. SelecteIdtem говорит вьюмодели со списком какой текущий табитем и та  уже просто выставит свойство у  нужной вьюмодели - список то у нее есть
2) сложный. сделать наследника табконтрол или аттачед/бехавиор, который при изменении таба пробежится по вкладкам, доберется до биндинга и изменит нужное свойство. Но это нужно умение такое писать.

Comment: В дополнение к @vitidev - свойство в головной ВМ от всего `TabControl` ещё удобнее будет тем, что его можно заполнять и менять активную вкладку, открывать сразу с нужной вкладки. А ваше свойство `IsSelected`, установленное в коде, сделает просто бинд невалидным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Вы можете создать стиль, чтобы добавить привязку для свойства `IsSelected` у вашего `TabItem'а` к свойству `IsSelected` во вью моделе.

Сделать это можно следующим способом (закинуть стиль с выставленным `TargetType'ом` в ресурсы контролу):

**XAML**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**CODE**

```
public class ItemViewModel {
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class Content {
    public Content() {
        items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>() {
            new ItemViewModel() {
                Header = "Tab 1",
                IsSelected = false
            },
            new ItemViewModel() {
                Header = "Tab 2",
                IsSelected = true
            }
        };
    }

    readonly IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items;
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return items; } }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Content();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не проверял, но это вроде не будет работать. Вы определили стиль, но нигде его не привязали к TabControl-у. Он просто болтается в ресурсах и нигде не используется.

Comment: Обязательно попробуйте, это сработает, стилю задан `TargetType` этого достаточно, чтобы его мог использовать `TabItem`, в данной ситуации

Comment: Аа, так он тогда будет применяться ко всем TabItem-ам в проекте или я не прав? Т.е. даже не относящимся с к этому TabControl-у. Если например у меня будет еще один TabControl...

Comment: @DarkByte безымянные стили считаются "по умолчанию" и применяются ко всем, для кого иное не задано. В данном случае, иерархия "ко всем" ограничена самим `TabControl`.

Comment: @DarkByte если вложить что-то в ресурсы или стили контрола, то это будет принадлежать только контролу. Так же работает преопределение системных цветов путем задания их в ресурсах контрола. На раз у TabItem есть IsSelected, то и проблемы нет (давно мсдн не читал)